# Issue with parallel execution with Selenium Grid for Webdriver + TestNG

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I am trying to set up Webdriver parallel execution with Webdriver Hub and TestNG parallel mechanism. I am facing an issue with thread

I have this class which extends TestBaseSetUp, which has a BeforeMethod and AfterMethod and set to run always. For webdriver parallel execution, I wanted to use ThreadLocal, but @Test and @Before/@After method are in different thread.So If I set webdriver as ThreadLocal in my TestBaseSetUp, and try get in my test method it returns null.

```
public class TestCheck extends TestBaseSetUp {
    @Test
    public void test(){
          System.out.println("Thread in test " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
```

}
}

Do we have a way so that @Test is also in same thread as @Before/@After method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Manish_pat

Take a look at this blog post of mine : https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/ 
The idea is to move away from relying on config methods for web driver instantiation into a TestNG listener driven model wherein the webdriver object is created from within the beforeInvocation() and destroyed in the afterInvocation().
TestNG guarantees that beforeInvocation(), @Test and afterInvocation() would always be executed on the same thread. So now you can go ahead and work with ThreadLocal in here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check the link, but I am wondering in this case how I would work with BeforeMethod and AfterMethod etc. Other than Test annotation, I would have to leave all these great features of testNG, since they are not in same thread as Test. Any suggestion for these.

Comment: If what I have suggested works fine for you, please do help accept the answer.
To answer to your question, I dont think BeforeMethod, Test, AfterMethod run on different threads. I responded to your query on the testng google forum with a sample as well. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/testng-users/8XYt-El2_JU/o5Mm6gklAQAJ

Answer (score 0):

did you tried

```
    @Test(singleThreaded=true)
```

At class level. so that all test methods in that class will run on same thread. [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/54) is example

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Thanks Murali for response. But I am wondering how this will solve the issue. My problem is when in my TestBaseSetUp BeforeMethod, I created the ThreadLocal driver and try to use it in Test method, but as BeforeMethod and Test methods are not in the same thread, it does not work.

Comment: hmm... bit confused. see if u use above annotation all test methods in class will run by same thread as per doc if i am not wrong.  so use normal method in TestBaseSetUp  class to create thread and call that thread in u r class may under BeforeTest. so BeforeTest, Test etc in that class will use same thread.